# How to override Quarkus @Retry.delay in a unit test?

Tags: java, junit, quarkus

I have a method:

```
@Retry(retryOn = SomeException.class, maxRetries = 5, delay = 180000, maxDuration = 360000)
public void checkIfSomethingIsReady() {
    if (something != ready) {
        throw new SomeException();
    } else {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do some boundary testing on a method like this without having to wait or retry. Is there a way to override this configuration solely for tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can,

> MicroProfile Fault Tolerance also allows configuration using
> MicroProfile Config. For example:

```
com.example.MyService/hello/Retry/delay=5
```

For the following code example:

```
@Singleton
public class MyService {
    @Retry(maxRetries = 10, delay = 180000, retryOn = IOException.class) 
    public String hello() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Therefore it would be `packagePath.ClassName/methodName/Retry/delay=yourNumber`

For tests, just have a different properties file with a different value.

Official Documentation: https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-fault-tolerance-3.0/microprofile-fault-tolerance-spec-3.0.html#_config_fault_tolerance_parameters

https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-fault-tolerance/5.0.0/usage/basic.html#_configuration

Comment: Just to complement, to change the time only in the test mode, you should add the `%test` prefix before the parameter. Coping @SMA answer, it would be like `%test.com.example.MyService/hello/Retry/delay=5`

Comment: @SMA thank you, i couldn't seem to figure out how to accomplish this without overriding the business logic method. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Felipe Windmoller, I just realized you can do this for test configs. It was a complete duh moment. Thanks for commenting!